# Possible bug in tagging selection system?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Just a minute ago I have some odd experience trying to find a tag under "Tags" section in the core "www.stackoverflow.com". I don't know if it is a bug but just in case I reported.The sequence that triggers the possible bug is as follows:

1. I was typing a tag (e.g. drupal, java) in the Tags section.
2. I clear my search box .. go from drupal to blank selection (nothing on the text box)
3. BUM Bug appears --- > The first item on the sorted list below was an awfull "blank tag" with 203 results.

Maybe it is ok to work that way (I really don't know). What I know is that some questions belong to the "blank space tag" and if I try to search only one blank space from the beginning of my search session it brings me back with the blank tag result. But what I'm saying here is when you clear the box (not even one miserable space) you get the same result and I think the average user will want to get back to the same set of results that it has when start.

Just a little odd behavior.  Maybe it's OK, I don't know.

For me it's still the best QA site on the world wide web rigth now.

Comment: What does this even look like? Post a comment with a link to your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I check again it's working right now!